Prettier rule to break all html elements inside a block the same way
I am using default NextJS eslint rules and have prettier activated in VS Code.
I am pretty sure this is a prettier configuration but basically when I am templating, I want all HTML elements inside a div to break the same way because I am using multi-select a lot and this only really works well if all elements inside a block are being treated the same.
e.g. I have this block:
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-12 gap-y-4 mt-12">
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Staked Supply</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Deployer Address</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Circulating Supply</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Treasury Contract</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">wTIA Liquidity</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Burnt Address</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">wTIA Price</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Vesting Contract</div>
          </div>

and prettier formats it to
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-12 gap-y-4 mt-12">
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Staked Supply</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">
              Deployer Address
            </div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">
              Circulating Supply
            </div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">
              Treasury Contract
            </div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">wTIA Liquidity</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">Burnt Address</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">wTIA Price</div>
            <div className="border-b border-[#87469E] pb-8">
              Vesting Contract
            </div>
          </div>

Thus, trying to select e.g. all the text now isn't a straightforward hotkey anymore.
Is there any way to tell prettier to keep these either all within one row or break them all?

Prettier is an opinionated formater, with only a small set of settings. Its purpose is not to generate the style/format you want, but a consistent format (which in this case would be to prevent long lines). You should be able to control it with print-width, but that would only work based on the line length.

As an example of what @t.niese is talking about. Prettier inserts closing slashes on self-closing tags much to the consternation and complaint of the W3C, WHATWG and MDN. Self-closing tags do not use or need closing slashes and they are not specified anywhere as necessary or needed.

@Rob <tag /> is a self-closing tag, but self-closing tags do not exist in HTML (they only exist in SVG or another foreign contexts); there are void elements that can't have child elements, and those elements don't have a closing tag (like br, input, ...). For those elements, a / can be placed before the >, but it is ignored. It isn't considered as a parsing error, but it is - iirc - only allowed because of the history of html/xhtml.

@t.niese That's what I said. But tags like <br> are self closing in that they do not need a closing tag. I've stated this, here, for years and get berated by mods for parroting the HTML standard and they hate that.

Prettier does not have a specific setting to force all elements inside a block to follow the exact same line-breaking behavior. The closest you can get is by tweaking printWidth and making sure your code adheres to the desired formatting.
You can configure such behavior through less opinionated tools like ESLint.

would you know a rule that applies for eslint?
